# Stuck in installing Taglist in Vim

Tags: plugins, tags, vim

I was trying to install Taglist in VIM and I did not understand this step:

> If the exuberant ctags utility is not
>   present in your PATH, then set the 
>       Tlist_Ctags_Cmd variable to point to the location of the exuberant ctags 
>       utility (not to the directory) in the .vimrc file.

What does it mean? If anybody uses this plugin, could you please help me congfigure it?

I downloaded the ctags and set my variable to

:let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd='C:\Program Files\Vim\ctags-5.7\ctags.exe'

But Im still getting "cannot generate tags" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ctags is a separate program you will need to install on your system.

http://ctags.sourceforge.net/

you'll want to look for install instructions for your specific operating system.

Once thats installed you can set that variable as specified if its not in your PATH

There is what seems to be thorough installation information here.

http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Comment: I downloaded ctags and set the variable with 
:let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd='C:\Program Files\Vim\ctags-5.7\ctags.exe'

But Im still getting an "Cannot generate tags" error.

Answer (score 3):

If you've installed ctags and you're still getting the `Taglist: Failed to generate tags` error like I was, make sure to use this format in your vimrc:

```
let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd = '"C:\Program Files\ctags58\ctags.exe"'
```

Note the double quotes inside the single quotes. I believe this is necessary when there are spaces in your string, and it's what made things work for me.